# How to return DateTime in different timezone from Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework, timezone

What is the pythonic way to return `DateTimeField` of some Django model using an arbitrary timezone in Django Rest Framework?

At the moment my view returns DateTime in UTC, because as far as I know Django stores timezone-aware datetimes as datetimes in UTC timezone.

Models:

```
class TimezoneMixin(models.Model):
    TIMEZONES = [(i, i) for i in country_timezones['ru']]

    timezone = models.CharField(choices=TIMEZONES, ...)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_timezone(self):
        if self.timezone:
            return timezone(self.timezone)
        return get_current_timezone()


class Organization(TimezoneMixin, models.Model):
    ...

class Event(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, ...)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, ...)
    ...
```

Serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('organization', 'date_created', ...)
```

In the ViewSet I populate data as follows

```
organization_id = ...  # Some logic to get required organization_id

data = {
    'date_created': timezone.now(), # django.utils.timezone
    'organization': organization_id,
    ...
}

serializer = EventSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    response_data = serializer.data.copy()
    # Some logic to rename one of the keys in response data
    ...
    return Response(response_data, ...)  # rest_framework.response.Response
```

Even if I replace `timezone.now()` with something like `timezone.now().astimezone(organization.get_timezone())` I still receive UTC DateTime in response.

Am I correct that it is not a good idea to parse `date_created` string from `response_data`, create a DateTime object from it, convert to different timezone and format as string again in the end of the view? What are the other ways?

Comment: The most sensible way would be to use timezone-aware or UTC everywhere, and only convert to local timezone at display time.

Comment: Am I wrong that datetimes can be timezone-aware and UTC at the same time?

Comment: They can (`timezone.now()` is). Then they are aware of being UTC.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have `USE_TZ = True` in settings. So I believe datetimes are already aware. Since this is API resource, am I correct that display time is just before returning response? In this case is it ok to parse string to datetime, switch timezone and format as a string back?

Comment: Ideally, the API should be in UTC. Display time is when presenting to the end user. For instance, in the JS code, you can query the browser for user's timezone and display accordingly. — Having local times in an API will just confuse developers as to which timezone it really is (does it depend on server location? is it UTC? is it set depending on some user setting? does it try do detect client timezone with geoip? what if I go through a proxy?)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I would also prefer to use UTC-based API as a user. However I have a requirement to send responses in different timezones because of current limitation of API clients.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) to get the time in the current time zone since `now()` will always return times in UTC regardless of the value of `TIME_ZONE`.

You can pass an arbitrary timezone to localtime:

```
localtime(timezone='SOMETHING')
```

Comment: Sounds almost like what I need. Could you suggest the place where it belongs? I've tried to put this logic to my custom `serializer.data`-like property of the serializer. But in case of custom property datetime is not auto-converted (serialized?) to string like it is in case of vanilla `serializer.data`. Not sure why yet.

Answer (score 2):

serializer uses default TIME_ZONE, which you set in settings.py file

If you want to set TIMEZONE for one field.

```
import pytz
class WeatherReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    DatetimeValue = serializers.DateTimeField(default_timezone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    
    class Meta:
        model = ...
        fields = [..., ..., ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get timestamp in arbitrary timezone without parsing datetime string because `serializer` provides access to saved `instance`. So below is my solution

```
response_data = serializer.data.copy()
# Some logic to rename one of the keys in response data
...
event_date_created_utc = serializer.instance.date_created
# Basically calls get_timezone on Organization instance and returns the result
organization_timezone = get_timezone_by_organization_id(organization_id)
response_data['date_created'] = timezone.localtime(event_date_created_utc,
                                                   timezone=organization_timezone).isoformat()
return Response(response_data, ...)  # rest_framework.response.Response
```

Thanks to Edgar R. Mondragón for mentioning `localtime()` and its usage.